# Identify this Amiga game: It's just like Rocket League

Tags: amiga, identify-this-game

I remember playing an Amiga game which was very similar to Rocket League, subject to the technology of the time.

It was a two player game with a top-down 2D playing area.  There was a large puck which the players would try to knock into the opposing goal.  Each player controlled a ship, and the ships traveled around on a low friction surface with approximately Newtonian physics.  Players could push the puck with their ship.  My recollection is that you could also shoot it to move it; you could shoot the opposing ship as well, though shots would not destroy it.

Players could choose from a selection of ships with different performance parameters (some were small and fast but couldn't push the puck very hard, others were big and strong but not very maneuverable, etc.)

Head to head play was possible, not sure if there was any provision for modem play.

I remember playing this game in the late 80s on an NTSC Amiga 2000.

Comment: Hmm.  I had a very similar game on the Spectrum.  Trying to remember what it was called, but drawing a blank.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may be thinking of Hyperbowl by Mastertronic. There's a [youtube video of the Atari ST version in action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_XxQUaehWU), which other than the improved graphics is very similar to the Spectrum version I had.  I've found references to an Amiga version existing, but no videos or images of it that I could find.

A free streaming copy of the Spectrum version is available on [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/zx_Hyperbowl_1986_Mastertronic).

Comment: Hyperbowl also existed for the Amiga Arcadia coin-op setup as [Blastaball](http://hol.abime.net/4197).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this one, Wild Wheels from Ocean: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oStzsQYLhKU